# How to deleting and recursing images?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made the image move from right to left.
But i wanna plus function that when image reach at x : 50, this image deleted
and to draw left.

I tried to using  control statement like "if" but it's not working

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "img1.png";
var speed = 0;
var xpos = 800;
var CXpos = 0;  //changeing xpos
var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;

function icon(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    speed -= 1;
    CXpos = xpos + speed;
    ctx.drawImage(img, CXpos, result, 60, 60);
    if(Cxpos == 50){
        canvas.width = canvas.width;    //I don't know it's correct code?
        icon();
    }
    ctx.closePath();
}

function iconypos(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random*100)+1
    return num;
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    icon();
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Comment: `to draw left` What do you mean? Also, `canvas.width = canvas.width;` will do nothing (the canvas width will remain the same).

Comment: @MoshFue "to draw left"  means that the image is deleted at the X: 50, then recreated on the right, and moved to the left.

Comment: So it will move from x:50 to the right infinitely, right?

Comment: No, the image that reaches x:50 is deleted, and the new image comes out. The image does not move right at x : 50.

Comment: Ok. Where is the new image come from. I mean is it have the same `src` or it's totally different one?

Comment: src is the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for. Just "reset" the `speed` var to the starting point (which is `0`).

No need to call to `icon()` again because the next tick in the interval will call this anyway.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/15933454?s=60&v=4";
var speed = 0;
var xpos = 800;
var CXpos = 0;  //changeing xpos
var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;

function icon(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    speed -= 1;
    CXpos = xpos + speed;
    ctx.drawImage(img, CXpos, result, 60, 60);
    if(CXpos == 50){
        speed = 0;    //I don't know it's correct code?
        //icon();
    }
    ctx.closePath();
}

function iconypos(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random*100)+1
    return num;
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    icon();
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas" width="800" height="350"></canvas>
```

Comment: Of course, Your answer said to me "You should study more."
Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: We all study all the time :) I glad I could help. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it may help to other people.